# How to reference UIAutomation assemblies in .NET Core 3 Project

Tags: c#, .net-core, ui-automation

I'm working on a netcore3.1 UI toolkit that needs to reference the Microsoft UIAutomation assemblies.  The UI Automation Overview page ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview)) states:

> UI Automation provides full functionality on supported Windows operating systems running the .NET Framework (see .NET Framework system requirements or versions of **.NET Core starting with .NET Core 3.0.**

But I can't figure out how to reference those assemblies from a netcoreapp3.1 project.

I searched my local drive for the files at they seem to be part of [this nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Runtime.win-x64/5.0.0-preview.6.20308.1) however the nuget page for it says:

> Internal implementation package not meant for direct consumption. Please do not reference directly.

How do I reference these assemblies?

---

Update: I found I can get references to these assemblies with this:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```

However this brings in about 140mb in almost 300 files covering all sorts of stuff I just don't need.  Surely there's a better way?

Comment: There is the [System.Windows.Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation?view=netcore-3.1) namespace which seems to be at least a little more lightweight than Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App but may not do everything you want it to. You may also want to check out [UIAComWrapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UIAComWrapper/)

Comment: @MindSwipe thanks.  Yes, that's the namespace but I need to know how to reference the defining assemblies. I looked at UIAComWrapper but it seems like Microsoft has the assemblies for this so I'd prefer use them.  The docs say I can use them, but not how to reference them.

Comment: Brad did you find an answer?  We need to move from net4.8 and have some automation as well.

Comment: @DanielWilliams  in the end I ditched the managed UIAutomation library and went with PInvoke/COM Interop to talk directly to the native COM libraries.  In my case I only needed the server side of things and this worked out well (ie: much simpler).